# Break to Else PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

So I have this code:

```
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $code = $_GET['code'];
    if (!array_key_exists($code, $errors)) {
        break 2;  // Move to else to do other stuff
    }
    // Do stuff
} else {
    // Do other stuff
}
```

But I can't get the break to do what I want it to do?
I just get an error:

> Fatal error: Cannot break/continue 2 levels in {filepath}\index.php on line 161 // Line of the !array_key_exists

So how can I get the if to break and move onto the else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `break` breaks loops like `for` or `while` ... it won't break `if`...

You can't move from `if` to `else` of that `if` ;-)

make it like this:

**EDIT AFTER COMMENT OF FRIENDLY USER**
*Fixed error with `$code` not assigned yet in `if`*

```
if (isset($_GET['code']) && array_key_exists($_GET['code'], $errors)) {
  $code = $_GET['code'];  
  // Do stuff
} else {
    do_other_stuff();
}
```

Comment: It'll show an error. Because `$code` has been initialized into the `block` but you have used it here `array_key_exists($code, $errors)`...

Comment: @73badf2bb626675fdd519011cbb39e You are totally right! edited.

Answer (score 2):

The `break` statement breaks out of the nearest enclosing `loop` or `switch` statement.

`break` does not break out of an `if` statement, but the nearest `loop` or `switch` that contains that if statement. The reason for not breaking out of an if statement is because it is commonly used to decide whether you want to break out of the `loop`.

Try like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['code']) && !array_key_exists($_GET['code'], $errors)) {
   // Do some stuff
else {
    // Do other stuff
}
```

Comment: he wants it to exist :-) so `array_key_exists()`, not `!array_key_exists()` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if (isset($_GET['code']) AND !(array_key_exists($GET['code'],$errors)) {
    $code = $_GET['code'];
}

elseif (isset($_GET['code']) AND $code = $_GET['code'] AND array_key_exists($code, $errors)) {
    // Do stuff
}

} else {
    // Do other stuff
}
```